# Generics in Java (Queue)

Tags: java, generics, queue, stack

i implemented a Stack Class.

Now, i want to create a Queue based on that stack. Like this :

```
public class Queue<E> {

    private Stack<E> next;
    private Stack<E> next2;

    public E first() {
        
    }
    public Queue<E> enqueue(E e) {
        
    }
    public Queue<E> dequeue() {
        
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.next == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Stack.isEmpty(next)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I don't know where to start. How can i solve this problem? My first ideas was to use the method "reverse" in Stack. But i'm not sure.

Comment: Your `Stack` class has no instance methods. `private Stack<E> next = Stack.create();` gives you a `Stack` that you can then `push` and `pop` onto with your `static` methods. Not ideal.

Comment: Well you can pop everything in another stack when you want to insert to queue, then insert to the original stack, that push everything for tmp stack to original one. Pop is done normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this. First one is to push at the end of stack using your function reverse. Like this

```java
public class Queue<E> {

    private Stack<E> next;

    public E front() {
        return (E) Stack.<E>top(next);
    }
    public Queue<E> enqueue(E e) {
        Stack<E> nextNew = Stack.reverse(next);
        nextNew = Stack.push(nextNew, e);
        nextNew = Stack.reverse(nextNew);
        Queue<E> q = new Queue<E>();
        q.next = nextNew;
        return q;
    }
    public Queue<E> dequeue() {
        Stack<E> nextNew = Stack.pop(next);
        Queue<E> q = new Queue<E>();
        q.next = nextNew;
        return q;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.next == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Stack.isEmpty(next)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I uploaded a basic structure of my code. Can you show me exactly what you mean (maybe edit my code)?

Comment: Hmm. Well i dont think you can do it the way you set your structure like. Queue needs to have whole stack. Then Insert(i guess thats enqueue) should insert in that stack you have. dequeue should remove from stack. But the difference is you need FIFO and not LIFO order. So i can type a queue based on your Stack but it will be different from the queue you just sent

Comment: The problem is that i'm not  allowed to use more than one private attribute. The method signatures are given to me. I shouldnt change them. I can reverse LIFO to FIFO with the reverse method in Stack

Comment: oh. okay then. That changes it. You can just push and then reverse. always do that and thats it. Try it out

Comment: Can you give me an exmaple? All this operations are based on Stack, but e.g. dequeue has ```Queue<E>```as a return type an not Stack.

Comment: @eliasmartin i think this is what you wanted. be free to correct me and ill edit it

Comment: Thank you! But i think there i still something wrong with front()

Comment: @eliasmartin well front returns the first one in queue, thats last one in stack. The front is all right. If its solution please tag it as solved

Comment: @eliasmartin ill add another way to implement this

Comment: I added a test to my question. In this case ``` assertEquals(Long.valueOf(4711L), q3.front());```i didnt returns 4711 but 2069

Comment: Well i have tested it and it is queue. Can you please provide me with that test. Maybe there is some edge case

Comment: The whole test is in my question. I edited it

Comment: Great, i see the problem. The queue that returns should be a copied queue and not the same one. Ill edit it soon

Comment: @eliasmartin here you go. It passes the test

Comment: Thank you!! I have to do the same with Set now. I hope i will make this

Comment: Can you maybe help me with another one?

Comment: Well post a new thread for other one. Its not about this topic

Comment: Okay, if you really want, you can check my new question.

Comment: ill check it out

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to add the `reverse()` method to Stack, which is a modification to Stack.  Of course, since all the methods are static, it could just as easily go in Queue, or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: @DaveB it was firstly said not to modify or add new methods to either stack or queue. So i didnt add anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's slickest with recursion:

```
public class Queue<E> {

    private Stack<E> stack;

    public Queue(Stack stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
    }

    public E front() {
        return Stack.top(stack);
    }

    public Queue<E> enqueue(E newValue) {
        if (Stack.top(stack) == null) {
          return new Queue(Stack.push(Stack.create(), newValue));
        }
        return new Queue<>(Stack.push(new Queue(Stack.pop(stack)).enqueue(newValue).stack, Stack.top(stack)));
    }

    public Queue<E> dequeue() {
        return new Queue<>(Stack.pop(stack));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Q: " + stack.toString();
    }
}
```

Note that there's no reversing required.

I thought some of the code in the Stack class was a little unclear with the "a" parameters and extra variables, so I refactored it a bit and stripped out everything that wasn't used.  I also added a `toString()` which traverses the stack recursively:

```
public class Stack<E> {

    private final E value;
    private final Stack<E> next;

    private Stack(E value, Stack<E> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static <E> Stack<E> create() {
        return new Stack<>(null, null);
    }

    public static <E> Stack<E> push(Stack<E> stack, E newValue) {
        return new Stack<E>(newValue, stack);
    }

    public static <E> Stack<E> pop(Stack<E> stack) {
        if (stack == null) {
            return new Stack<E>(null, null);
        } else if (stack.value == null) {
            return new Stack<>(null, null);
        } else if (stack.next == null) {
            return new Stack<E>(null, null);
        } else {
            return stack.next;
        }
    }

    public static <E> E top(Stack<E> stack) {
        if (stack == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (stack.value == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return stack.value;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (Stack.top(next) == null) {
            return (value != null ? value.toString() : "Null");
        }
        return (value != null ? value.toString() : "Null") + " " + next.toString();
    }
}
```

And a little testing class.  To show the difference between the stack and the queue, it loads up a stack first, then passes it to a Queue and adds a few more elements, then pulls a few off the front:

```
public class QueueWithStackMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> stack = Stack.create();
        stack = Stack.push(stack, "1");
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        stack = Stack.push(stack, "2");
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        stack = Stack.push(stack, "3");
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        Queue<String> queue = new Queue<>(stack);
        System.out.println(queue.toString());
        queue = queue.enqueue("4");
        System.out.println(queue.toString());
        queue = queue.enqueue("5");
        System.out.println(queue.toString() + " -> " + queue.front());
        queue = queue.dequeue();
        System.out.println(queue.toString() + " -> " + queue.front());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he cant change Stack or add new methods to queue.

Comment: @Dusan Todorovic He's changed the question.  I refactored Stack just for clarity without changing it's functionality at all, and the only method I added to Queue was a constructor.

Comment: I made a quick update.  The enqueue() method was overly complicated because it didn't take the recursion all the way down to a Null Stack.  Once that was done, it became trivial.  The whole Queue class is only 25 lines now - including the toString().